# I have a 'end if without block if' in visual basic when it compiles

Tags: vb6

I am having a problem when I compile my .exe file is says this is the source of the fault. Can anyone recreate this code for me?

```
Private Sub tmrCounter_Timer()

cntCounter = cntCounter + 1

tmrLogger.Enabled = False
SendCurrentInfos
cntCounter = 0
tmrCounter.Enabled = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Any particular programming language ?

Comment: Its in visual basic 6 I'm not sure I did not create the code it's just not allowing me to compile it.

Comment: Please add suitable tags so that people know what you're asking about. Also try and format your code to make it readable (there's a button in the editor for this).

Comment: The compiler is telling you exactly what is wrong.  What do you expect the 'End If' line to do?

Comment: I know I need to put an If in, but where?

Comment: @michaelburridge You could put the `If` between any 2 lines.  What is the condition you want to test?  What are you expecting this function to do?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you need an `If`. You probably just need to remove the `end if`.

However you may need an `If` as you are incrementing a counter at top of the procedure, and later set it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that the last 3 lines inside the sub should be:

```
if cntCounter = 0
  tmrCounter.Enabled = False
End If
```

it all depends on the value of cntCounter though, as it always increases in value it should be negative at the start to arrive at 0 at some time, or be altered somewhere else in your code